# Books - Deep learning and recurrent neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, references

I have read with interest the Elements of Statistical Learning and Murphy's Machine Learning - a Probabilistic Perspective. The latter touches upon deep learning and deep / recurrent neural networks in the last chapter, but I was wondering if new books / sources have come out that go into more depth on these topics?

Answer (score 5):

There's a work-in-progress book on Deep Learning by Ian Goodfellow, Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville. It's not finished yet, but you can view the draft [online](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/), it has a chapter on recurrent networks.

Answer (score 3):

There are more resources available. I have listed a few below (no affiliation with any of them).

For a collection of information on Recurrent Neural Networks look [here](https://github.com/kjw0612/awesome-rnn).

For a collection of information on deep learning look [here](https://github.com/ChristosChristofidis/awesome-deep-learning)

Check the deep learning part of the website of [H2O](http://h2o.ai/product/deep-learning/)

You can also look at the [journal of machine learning research](http://www.jmlr.org) if there are any articles available. Or look at [arXiv](http://arxiv.org). Even [SSRN](http://www.ssrn.com) has some articles about this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any book better than http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/

I think the book is the best because:

- It's easy to read and not much mathematics
- There's a Github source code for the book
- The book talks about advanced concepts such as dropout and gradient vanishing

Comment: Thank you. Great book. Does it cover recurrent neural networks?